# Javascript roll over and hide parts of page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an issue with the roll over and change the cursor to a hand on a hover over two images here is the code I use for the hide/display:

```
<div class="listing">
<span style="float:right; margin:-10px 100px 0px 20px;">Change view:&nbsp;</span>
<input class="listing" id="List" style="visibility: hidden;" name="listing" onclick="hideForm()" type="radio">
<label class="listing" for="List"> 
<img src="/devsite/images/icons/row.png" alt="List" title=" List " border="0"></label>


<input class="listing" id="Grid" style="visibility: hidden;" name="listing" onclick="hideForm()" type="radio">
<label class="listing" for="Grid">
<img src="/devsite/images/icons/table.png" alt="Grid" title=" Grid " border="0"> </label>
</div>

    <div id="formdiv"  style="display: block;"> some stuff </div>

    <div id="formdiv2"  style="display: block;">    some different stuff </div>
```

The javascript :

```
<script language="javascript">
function hideForm(){
if (document.getElementById('List').checked==true){
  document.getElementById('formdiv').style.display="block";
  document.getElementById('formdiv2').style.display="none";
} else {
  document.getElementById('formdiv').style.display="none";
  document.getElementById('formdiv2').style.display="block";
};

if (document.getElementById('Grid').checked==true){
  document.getElementById('formdiv').style.display="none";
  document.getElementById('formdiv2').style.display="block";
} else {
  document.getElementById('formdiv').style.display="block";
  document.getElementById('formdiv2').style.display="none";
};


}

</script>
```

What I need is a roll over cursor change, and background color change on selected radio buttons...the hide/show visible are working fine

Comment: Can you add the html code for the radio buttons?

Comment: Are you using jQuery? I don't see it in your javascript.

Comment: jquery-1.10.1.min.js  is loaded,  The radio buttons use an image based on the label for="" which works fine...

Comment: <input class="listing" id="List" style="visibility: hidden;" name="listing" onclick="hideForm()" type="radio">

Answer (score 0):

For `background` color change you can use this:

`YourElement.style.background = "#000000"`

For `cursor` change:

`YourElement.style.cursor = "type"`

For different types of the cursor: [cursor types doc](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/playit.asp?filename=playcss_cursor&preval=initial)

Comment: Would I use this in the javascript area ie:  listing.style.background = "#000000"

Comment: Yes, inside your conditions. e.g. You want to change the background color when you check the `List` than you put it inside the `List` condition.

Answer (score 0):

To display a cursor on hover try the following css:

```
img:hover {
cursor:pointer;
}
```

For the background, using jquery you can do the following:

```
$("#elementid").css("background", "#000000")
```

Answer (score 0):

I have changed the radio code to :

```
<span style="float:right; margin:-10px 100px 0px 20px;">Change view:&nbsp;</span>
<input class="listing" id="List" style="visibility: hidden;" name="listing" onclick="hideForm()" type="radio">
<label class="List" for="List"> 
<img src="/devsite/images/icons/row.png" alt="List" title=" List " border="0"></label>


<input class="listing" id="Grid" style="visibility: hidden;" name="listing" onclick="hideForm()" type="radio">
<label class="Grid" for="Grid">
<img src="/devsite/images/icons/table.png" alt="Grid" title=" Grid " border="0"> </label>

                        </span>
```

and the javascript to:

```
<script language="javascript">
function hideForm(){
if (document.getElementById('List').checked==true){
  document.getElementById('formdiv').style.display="block";
  document.getElementById('formdiv2').style.display="none";
  List.style.background = "#FFFFFF";
  Grid.style.background = "#111111";
  List.style.cursor = "pointer";
  Grid.style.cursor = "pointer";
} else {
  document.getElementById('formdiv').style.display="none";
  document.getElementById('formdiv2').style.display="block";
  List.style.background = "#111111";
  Grid.style.background = "#FFFFFF";
  List.style.cursor = "pointer";
  Grid.style.cursor = "pointer";
};

if (document.getElementById('Grid').checked==true){
  document.getElementById('formdiv').style.display="none";
  document.getElementById('formdiv2').style.display="block";
  List.style.background = "#111111";
  Grid.style.background = "#FFFFFF";
  List.style.cursor = "pointer";
  Grid.style.cursor = "pointer";
} else {
  document.getElementById('formdiv').style.display="block";
  document.getElementById('formdiv2').style.display="none";
    List.style.background = "#FFFFFF";
  Grid.style.background = "#111111";
    List.style.cursor = "pointer";
  Grid.style.cursor = "pointer";
};


}
</script>
```

this is just getting messy.....